# How to uninstall Mysql Shell on MacOS

Tags: mysql

I've wrongly installed MySql Shell https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-shell/8.0/en/ in my MacBook Pro.
I've confused it from the standard mysql shell command.

Now, all works ok, but I doesn't need MySql Shell... so there is a way to uninstall MySql Shell from my MacOS?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

cd /usr/local/bin

sudo rm -rf mysqlsh

cd ..

sudo rm -rf mysql-shell

sudo rm -rf mysql-shell-8.0.20-macos10.15-x86-64bit/

Then restart your command line and it would not recognize anymore the command mysqlsh.

I think this is because the global paths are loaded from the file /etc/paths and the executable is not anymore in the directories =).

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what Alex said above, I think it's important to 'forget' the package as well to remove the last trace of the shell from your system: `sudo pkgutil --forget com.mysql.shell`