# Confused with different types of MySQL applications to install

Tags: mysql, shell, mysql-workbench, homebrew

I'm very new to MySQL.

My question is about installation of MySQL on my Mac (Mojave OS) to learn and practice it to later use it with node.js.

First I got it with Homebrew, but then I wasn't able to use it with the Workbench - I set up the password for root user but I didn't find any commands list to work with it since it refused to do any operations with it in workbench and I didn't find any command.

Then I downloaded Community Server - I have a server through system prefs, but I don't have a command line interface - which I need for writing queries.

After that I downloaded MySQL Shell. But as far as I researched I found that is it not standard CLI (found it here `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58367813/how-to-uninstall-mysql-shell-on-macos`).

My question is next.

As an example, when I started learning MongoDB I had MongoDB Compass and MongoDB Shell - one helped me to work with commands, the other one helped to see results visually.

MySQL has a language which I want to learn and practice with (SELECT, USE etc.). How can I do the same what I did with MongoDB but in the case of MySQL? What should I install, and why Homebrew MySQL version is different than any other MySQL version (even commands - such as mysql.server start) and there is no documentation for it in MySQL docs?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there's no such nice installer for macOS as there is for [Windows](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/). Instead you have to install the different parts individually.

For the type of work you plan to do I recommend to install at least 2 pieces:

- The [MySQL server](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/), which holds your data. On macOS this comes with a preferences pane, which you can use do some basic management of the server (start/stop, directory settings).

[image]

- [MySQL Workbench](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/), a visual design, query and management tool. That will give you GUI support for your DB work.

[image]

The server also comes with the classic shell, which you can launch by running `mysql` in a terminal. That's sometimes quicker for simple work, compared to launching a full GUI.

A better command line tool is the [MySQL Shell](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/shell/), a new and highly improved variant of the classic shell, which will eventually replace the old classic shell entirely in the future. So it's certainly no mistake to install that too.

[image]

I hope that clarifies which pieces are required to start working with MySQL.

Comment: Mike, I’ll try that in a couple of hours and let you know

Comment: Thanks too much! Hope I will get it properly.